# Netbook thinks it is a desktop

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, netbook

Question:

Are, and if so what, there packages for download that I can get netbook to understand it is not a desktop and that it is a netbook.

---

Info:

I'm running an Acer Aspire One with ubuntu desktop 9.10. I tried Ubuntu Netbook Remix first but it has graphics issues with the aspire one. So I changed to Ubuntu Desktop. It was the only distro (after debian, centOS, Fedora, and Knoppix all failed me) that I managed to get working. The only thing is that it is having issues doing things that a netbook/laptop should be doing. most notably is that it will run it's battery dead if I close the screen and throw it into my back pack. It seems to just stay fully on and runs it's self to death. also it will lock up some times if I close the screen and come back to it 10 or 20 minutes later. It also won't retain volume settings when I reboot, as well as screen brightness. and just a couple of other things that I can't quite put my finger on, but just seem amiss. like I said, Essentially my netbook thinks it is a desktop, how can I fix this?

~N

Comment: Doctor, doctor! I think I'm a dog. *sit on the couch and we will discuss your issue.* Doctor, I'm not allowed on the couch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest first checking under System->Preferences for the gnome power management settings.  From here you should be able to correctly configure your OS's power saving features.  If you don't have the power management option you, for some reason, may not have the packages installed. Check the synaptec package manager and look for the following packages:

- *gnome-power-manager*
- *powermanagement-interface*
- *powermgmt-base*
- *powernowd*

Verify they're installed either through the gui or through the terminal via:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep power
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @~quack Thanks for the format edit. :D